# On the influences of i-th token's MASK to i'th token's predicted distributions in BERT masked language models

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, nlp

In the paper of XLNet, it is explained that the masking technique has a drawback because only when BERT models are pretrained tokens which are replaced with MASK symbols in part (fraction 15% ~ 20%) but ,in finetune process, no input has masked token.

My first question is :

Can BERT pre-trained masked language models( whose weights are freezed )  output a kind of natural distributions of the i-th token when an input sentence's i-th token is MASKED ? (This setting is meaningless in all applications to other NLP tasks but my intent is to understand the role of MASK.)

In here, unlikely token means two patterns: the first one is ulikeliness in the pretrain corpus such as the sentence "I bite a dog everyday" which has more likely sentence "A dog bite me yesterday" or "I pat a dog everyday." according to the common sense, and the second pattern is a grammar errors like "I bought a  milk everyday." instead of "I buy a milk everyday". So, my question is asking when "I MASK a dog everyday" and "I byte a dog everyday" are inputted into the same pretrained BERT model using large corpora with common senses and correct grammars, then do two corresponding prredicted distributions have greatly different shape ?

If the answer to the first question is yes, then can I check the difference of distributions between unusual sentence and the sentence whose unusual tokens are MASKED through KL divergence function of these two predicted distributions ?